# Forward a servlet request to another server

Tags: http, servlets, jersey, portforwarding

Java Servlet API can forward requests to another path within the same server (*identical host:port*). But, forwarding to a different host:port — like proxy do — is another story.

I've tried to do that with Jersey Client, adapting the [ServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) — method, headers, mediatype and body — to a Jersey [ClientRequest](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientRequest.html) (*with a different base uri*), making the call, and adapting back the Jersey [ClientResponse](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/ClientResponse.html) — method, headers, mediatype and body — to the [ServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html).

Adapting those manually seems wrong to me.

Isn't there a pure Servlet API solution? 
Or an HTTP client capable of adapting requests back and forth when changing the host:port?

Answer (score 9):

[HTTP-Proxy-Servlet](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet) does exactly what you need.

## Quick configuration

#### pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy</groupId>
    <artifactId>smiley-http-proxy-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

#### web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>solr</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetUri</param-name>
        <param-value>http://solrserver:8983/solr</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>solr</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/solr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

## Spring Integration

see also: [HTTP-Proxy-Servlet Issue #15](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet/issues/15)

#### pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy</groupId>
    <artifactId>smiley-http-proxy-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

#### ServletWrappingControllerExt.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController;

public class ServletWrappingControllerExt extends ServletWrappingController
{
    private String  pathToStrip;

    public void setPathToStrip(String pathToStrip)
    {
        this.pathToStrip = pathToStrip;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception
    {
        final HttpServletRequest wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request)
        {
            @Override
            public String getPathInfo()
            {
                //Please note that getPathInfo returns null if DispatcherServlet is configured to track url-pattern "/"
                //It should be configured to track url-pattern "/*". Below is a sample DispatcherServlet configuration
                /*
                    <servlet>
                        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                    </servlet>
                    <servlet-mapping>
                        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                    </servlet-mapping>
                 */
                String path = super.getPathInfo();                  
                if (path.startsWith(pathToStrip))
                {
                    final int length = pathToStrip.length();
                    path = path.substring(length);
                }
                return path;
            }
            
            @Override
            public String getServletPath()
            {
                return super.getServletPath();
            }
        };

        return super.handleRequestInternal(wrapper, response);
    }
}
```

#### Beans configuration

```
<bean id="myServletWrapper" class="ServletWrappingControllerExt">
    <property name="pathToStrip" value="/solr"/>
    <property name="servletClass" value="org.mitre.dsmiley.httpproxy.ProxyServlet" />
    <property name="servletName" value="solr" />
    <property name="initParameters">
        <props>
            <prop key="targetUri">http://solrserver:8983/solr</prop>
            <prop key="log">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myServletUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="urlMap">
    <map>
        <entry key="/solr/**" value-ref="myServletWrapper" />
    </map>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [javax.net.HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

**Here is the psuedo code for that:**

```
URL url = new URL("http://otherserver:otherport/url");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

// set http method if required
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

// set request header if required
connection.setRequestProperty("header1", "value1");

// check status code
if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {

   InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
   //transfer is to the required output stream
} else {
   //write error
}
```

Comment: I tried this, just copy pasted the same code, but I am getting response code = -1 and with IOException having detailed message as "Invalid Http response", can you pelase help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand You need to send `request`s from Servlet and get `response` from other server into yours, may be you need a [HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) ([Overview](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)) for that.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10857386/803285) question might also help you.