# Change the servlet header and redirect to other url in a filter

Tags: java, http, servlets, http-headers

I'm very new to servlet and I wish to do the following.

I have a filter set up in my place:

```
void doFilter( ServletRequest request, 
               ServletResponse response, 
               FilterChain chain ) throws IOException, ServletException 
{
}
```

these filters will be called when certain url matches with the pattern.

Inside this method, I wish to do this:

1. Change the incoming `request` header by putting the authenticaton key which I know
2. And with that authentication header in place redirect the `request` to other url like `www.test.com` so that the response of that particular request will be the result of the `www.test.com`

Is it possible to do so?

I tried these:

```
response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate","Basic MyKey")
response.setHeader("Location","www.google.com")
```

But after this what should I do? How do I redirect the page to google.com?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have *you* tried?

Comment: I tried looking to set the authorization header for the `request` object. But I don't find any methods for it over http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about `RequestDispatcher` using - you couldn't send forward to remote server with it. I don't know, how to forward your request with custom header out of your `ServletContext`. And I found similar question without answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860569/forward-a-servlet-request-to-another-server . Maybe it's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

That's (fortunately) not possible. It would be a huge security breach if you could as being the web server control the headers of HTTP requests fired by the web client to arbitrary domains. It would make among others phishing very easy.

To achieve what you need, your best bet is to act as a proxy. Create and fire the HTTP request yourself  programmatically using e.g. `URLConnection` or Apache HTTPComponents Client and pipe its response to the servlet response. Do however note that the URL in the browser address bar stays the URL of your web server.

Here's a kickoff example using `URLConnection`:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://other.com").openConnection();
// Set headers if necessary via setRequestProperty().

InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
// Copy response body from input to output.
```